# Unintentionally Transparent Vector Artwork

Tags: vector, transparency

I have used a vector image I purchased. If I use it over another element in the design, the vector appears transparent. Everywhere I have looked in Photoshop (CS6), the vector is at 100% opacity. I don't understand why this is happening. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

Have you opened the Vector file in a vector editing program like **Illustrator?** It is highly likely that the opacity may have been applied onto the layers themselves within illustrator and it's this opacity that is reflected in Photoshop.

> The opacity that  you are trying to adjust is applying to the entire
>   opacity of the image, but not the individual vector layers that make
>   up the image.

Try to open the vector image in illustrator >> Select all layers and change the opacity to 100% >> Open it within Photoshop then.